# How to point TTS install intent to the amazon app store?

Tags: android

I have an android app that uses TextToSpeech.  I check to see if the TTS package is installed by starting the `TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA` intent.  If the intent checking to see if the TTS package exists comes back with a result that it doesn't exist, then I kick off the intent to install the TTS package:

```
Intent installIntent = new Intent();
installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
startActivity(installIntent);
```

This intent will launch a link to the market, but I'm not sure how it decides which tts package to install.  Does it always point to the same tts app?  Is there a way I can make it point to the amazon app store, or which tts package in the amazon app store should I be pointing the user to for my amazon version of my app?  Amazon rejected my app submission because the `TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA` intent was pointing the user to the android market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't. I don't even know if the TTS data is on the Amazon Appstore. You have two options:

- explain to the Amazon people that you were using the system intent, and didn't point it to Market explicitly. Presumably, on a Amazon device (Kindle Fire, etc.) this intent will go to their store by default.
- Set a flag in your Amazon version, and skip the TTS check altogether.

Comment: I contacted amazon and they made an exception for this case since I wasn't pointing to the market explicitly.  Thanks for your help.